# htaccess redirection virtual folder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i just got a FTP access to an old server, with architecture:

```
index.php
page1.php
page2.php
.htaccess
archives/
  - page1.php
  - page2.php
  - ...
new/
  - Web/
    - frontend.php
    - Images/
      - ...
    - CSS/
      - ...
```

The new site is accessible requesting on /, but i want the old site (the page1.php, page2.php ...) to be accessible requesting on /old/

I don't want to move all files into an 'old' folder, i would like to use only htaccess file, rewriting the address.

I spent 4 hours on it, but i can't get any solution.

Here is an example of my last htaccess, working for the new website but not for the old one:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^old/css/(.*).css$ css/$1.css [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^old/images/(.*)$ images/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^old/files(.*)$ files$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^old. index.php [QSA,L] 

RewriteRule ^css/(.*).css$ new/Web/css/$1.css [QSA,L,NS]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ new/Web/images/$1 [QSA,L,NS]
RewriteRule ^files(.*)$ new/Web/files$1 [QSA,L,NS]

RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" !-f
RewriteRule .* new/Web/frontend.php [L]
```

Thks !

Comment: Can  you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: I added my last htaccess. I can't access to the old website, but the new one is working